# If $corr(A,B)=1$, and $cov(A,C) \neq 0$, do we have $cov(B,C)\neq 0$ as well?

Tags: correlation, covariance

If $corr(A,B)=1$, and $cov(A,C) \neq 0$, do we have $cov(B,C)\neq 0$ as well?

I understand $cov(A,B) \neq 0$ and $cov(A,C) \neq 0$ don't imply $cov(B,C) \neq 0$. And I am looking for a counter-example of the case where $A,B$ are perfectly correlated. A non-trivial example that doesn't involve a degenerate random variable would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is perfect correlation, the variables are linearly related, i.e. $A=mB+n$ where $m\neq0$. This yields $\operatorname{cov}(B,C)=m\operatorname{cov}(A,C)\neq 0$.

Comment: Worth adding that $m \ne 0$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @gunes, I think I almost get it now, I have the following argument which seems convincing at least to myself, so I post it to make the answer more complete and to accept any criticism:

WLOG, we can express $A$ as $A=mB+n$, just lettting $n:=A-mB$ denote the difference, then we have:

$corr(A,B)=\frac{cov(mB+n,B)}{\sqrt{var(B)var(mB+n)}}=1\\
\Rightarrow m^2 var(B)^2+ cov(n,B)^2 + 2m*var(B) cov(B,n) = var(B)[m^2var(B)+var(n)+2m*cov(B,n)]\\
\Rightarrow cov(n,B)^2 = var(B)var(n)$

Especially, in the above argument, we can choose arbitrarily m, and let $m'=\frac{cov(A,B)}{var(B)}$, we have $cov(n',B)=cov(A-m'B,B)=cov(A,B)-\frac{cov(A,B)}{var(B)}cov(B,B)=0$. This combines with the last line $cov(n',B)^2 = var(B)var(n') =0 \Rightarrow var(n')=0$ provided that $B$ is non-degenerated. And $var(n')=0$ implies $n'$ is degenerated (constant).

Therefore, we have $cov(B,C)=\frac{1}{m'}cov(A,C) \neq 0$, the fact that $m' \neq 0$ is implicitly implied by $A$ is also non-degenerated and hence $cov(A,B) \neq 0$.